# Docker - Multiple duplicate volume declarations; what happens?

Tags: mysql, docker, volume, dockerfile

I'm trying to set up a persistent data volume for my MySQL docker container.

I'm using the official MySQL image which has this in the Dockerfile:

> VOLUME /var/lib/mysql

If I invoke

> -v /var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql

during runtime, does my command take precedence, or do I have to remove the VOLUME declaration from the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#volume - the `VOLUME` command is declaring a mount point so it can be used by other hosts with the `--volumes-from` as well the `VOLUME` command tells docker that the contents of this directory is external to the image.  While the `-v /dir1/:/dir2/` will mount dir1 from the host into the running container at dir2 location.

In other words, you can use both together and docker will mount the `-v` properly.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what i needed to know!

Comment: @Chockomonkey can you help me understand the '--volumes-from' bit.  If an image defines a VOLUME in the dockerfile like '/tmp', this means that my host dir will NOT be mounted (i would have to use -v for that), so what is the point in declaring VOLUME at all? I assume it's to do with '--volumes-from', just not sure I follow how this works in practice.

Comment: @JamesC The way I understand it, the VOLUME command in the Dockerfile simply exposes the location inside the container to be used by other containers via the --volumes-from command.